# How do I search any of the Stack Exchange sites using regular expressions?

Tags: feature-request, search

I could have avoided asking a duplicated question had I been able to use *extended* regular expressions.

Duplicated question is [What is the origin of the "r" in resistance measurements?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61141/what-is-the-origin-of-the-r-in-resistance-measurements?noredirect=1#comment117360_61141)

Had I been able to search for answers using an expression akin to:

```
\b[0-9]+R[0-9]+\b
```

then I might have seen the other answer and not added the duplicate question.

Is there a way to do that within the Stack Exchange?

Comment: Nice idea! You'll get a better response on Meta.SO I think, this is network-wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can use [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to run arbitrary SQL queries (read-only, of course) against any site in the network.

However, Stack Exchange uses Microsoft SQL Server which doesn't support regular expressions. The closest you'll get is some very [limited pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489.aspx) (`LIKE` syntax). Even the simple regular expression you suggest can't be expressed with the limited syntax, though.

Stack Exchange does offer a few APIs that you might be able to use to do this: http://api.stackexchange.com/. I haven't looked at the API at all, so I'm not sure if it has the same limitation as the Data Explorer (or what is possible with it).

You could always query a larger, unfiltered data set from the API(s) and filter it with regular expressions on the client side (i.e. your own application).

I agree with Keelan that you should ask this at SO Meta. Data Explorer is cared for by SQL ninjas, so I'm sure they can provide a definite answer/maybe even offer to implement the feature :)

Comment: Thanks.  I marked this as the answer. I should have been a bit more clear in my question in that I wanted a way to do this from the existing website, not via having to code up something using API's, therefore the answer is actually "no" or at least not yet.

Comment: @bgoodr: You're welcome!  
You should try asking on Meta - they might be able to implement this. I can ask if you'd prefer.